# Can I disable warnings about IP conflicts?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip-address

Running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. I travel with my laptop back and forth between home and the office, and usually hibernate as opposed to shutting down, so I do not need to reopen all the documents and junk that I am working on.

The one annoying thing though, is that coming from the home network to the office, when I boot back up, I usually get a warning popup about an IP conflict detected.

Is there any way to turn off that warning, and just have it silently query the DHCP server for a new address without the need to tell me about it?

Comment: My "solution" to a similar problem was to write a program that would renew DHCP leases whenever the system went back from sleep. I could post the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your office and home IP ranges are the same or a subrange if you get a conflict so you could try to change your Home IP range and I think there will be no more conflict. The network card would request a new IP automatically as the one you have from home will not work in your office network.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unelegant but working:

Create a batch file and execute it each time you get back from sleep...

Open notepad and write:

ipconfig /renew

Save the file with .bat extension (deselect the *.txt in the save page and select *.* and then add the full name: script.bat), right click on it and then properties - compatibility and check the flag execute as administrator.

Each time you get out of the sleep a simple double click and it's done.

I don't know how to load it automatically when coming out from sleep: sorry.